# How can rough sets be applied in data mining?

Tags: data-mining, fuzzy

I read some articles where theory of rough sets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_set) is also considered as data mining algorithm. However, I have not found so far any example when this theory may be useful in solving data mining problems. I am also wondering that there is no R package for rough sets manipulation.

Could you give me some examples or situations, when rough sets are the most appropriate technique for analysis?

Comment: Links, or at least references, to these articles would help make this an answerable question.

Comment: For example, rough sets are mentioned as data mining tool in http://www.comp.dit.ie/btierney/BSI/Data%20Mining%20Tool%20Reviews%20March%202011.pdf .